# dialogflow storing and updating values in flow

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a chatbot that takes orders in dialogflow. I want to have a total cost variable that starts at zero, and when the users says yes I would like to buy a coffee, I would add $1 to total cost. Then after if the user says he wants to order an ice cream I add $5, making total cost $6. Is this doable with out any external code through dialogflows UI? If not what are my options?

EDIT: I am using the facebook messenger integration

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with the Dialogflow web client alone. You can store the cost in a [context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts), but you can not interact with existing contexts in Dialogflow itself. For that you would have to implement a fulfillment webhook.

Note that if you are building you own webhook there is now a special API for these kinds of transactions: [Transactions](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/).